# python launches a different version depending on user

Tags: python, solaris-10

I have an odd one.  Different users executing the same python binary on the same Solaris 10 server get different versions with different modules..

This all started because a script runs fine as root (finds pexpect module), but fails as any other user (fails to find pexpect module).

Running python as me I get python 2.6.4

```
Sandman HDS1234567 $ python -V
Python 2.6.4
Sandman HDS1234567 $ which python
/opt/csw/bin/python
```

If I sudo to root, I get python 2.6.8

```
Sandman HDS1234567 $ sudo -s
Password:
bash-3.2# which python
/opt/csw/bin/python
bash-3.2# python -V
Python 2.6.8
bash-3.2#
```

Even explicitly calling python with the full path shows the same odd behavior..

```
Sandman HDS1234567 $ whoami ; /opt/csw/bin/python -V
mperino
Python 2.6.4

Sandman HDS1234567 $ sudo -s
Password:
bash-3.2# whoami ; /opt/csw/bin/python -V
root
Python 2.6.8
```

How can the same binary be 2 different versions???

Comment: The file /opt/csw/bin/python is a binary:  
#file /opt/csw/bin/python  
/opt/csw/bin/python:    ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+ Required, dynamically linked, stripped  
and the package info is:  
# pkginfo -l CSWpython  
   PKGINST:  CSWpython  
      NAME:  python - A high-level scripting language, 2.6 series  
  CATEGORY:  application  
      ARCH:  sparc  
   VERSION:  2.6.8,REV=2013.02.27  
   BASEDIR:  /  
    VENDOR:  http://python.org/download/releases/2.6.8 packaged for CSW by Maciej Blizinski  
    PSTAMP:  maciej@unstable10s-20130227151141

Comment: Most likely `/opt/csw/bin/python` is actually a wrapper around multiple different Pythons (much like Apple's `/usr/bin/python` is a wrapper around 2.5, 2.6, or 2.7), and which one it's selecting depends on some environment variables. But without seeing your environment, or what so's that `python` is linked to, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: It's not a symlink or a wrapper script.. Seems to be a Solaris Binary. Running "file" against it shows it as a "ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC32PLUS Version 1, V8+"  Which is the puzzling part..  Why would the binary launch a different version depending on the user?

Comment: Well, it's obviously not a symlink. But how does the fact that it's a binary rather than a script mean that it's not a wrapper? Apple's `/usr/bin/python` is a `Mach-O universal binary`. Windows `py.exe` is a `PE executable`. And that's exactly why I asked which so's that `python` is linked to—that question wouldn't make any sense if it were a script.

Comment: Im further down the rabbit hole and I now understand what's triggering it to select the older version, but I dont like the logic.

If LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains /usr/lib then it launches 2.6.4
If LD_LIBRARY_PATH is blank, or does not contain /usr/lib then it launches 2.6.8

looking in /usr/lib there are links from libpython2.6.so -> libpython2.6.so.1.0, and libpython2.6_db.so -> libpython2.6_db.so.1.0

Im assuming those libraries are what are causing it to select that version.

Comment: That sounds like the problem. If you've got `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set for your user, but not for root, all kinds of things are going to work differently. Is there a reason you're setting it in the first place? If not, just don't. If so, because you need it in general, but don't want it here, just write yourself an alias or script that unsets it in a subshell and runs python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `/opt/csw/bin/python` is either a minimal executable that links to `libpython2.6.so` without an absolute path and defers to it, or a wrapper around an executable that itself ultimately links to `libpython2.6.so` without an absolute path.

In your user environment, you've got an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set, which causes `/usr/lib/libpython2.6.so` to be selected. In your root environment, you don't, so a different Python (maybe `/opt/csw/lib/libpython2.6.so`, but that's just a guess) is selected. And most of the guts of the interpreter are in the .so, not the executable.

So, the first question is, why are you specifying that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the first place? If you don't need it, don't set it. Or, if you *do* need it, why doesn't root need it?

But if this is all a workaround for some other problem that you can't solve any other way, the simplest solution is to write an alias/function/script that runs Python in a subshell with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set/unset as appropriate.